# Is there a website that summarizes the luggage and check-in requirements for each airplane company?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, planning

I don't travel much by plane but I use a wide variety of companies. Since there is not much harmonization, specially with LCC, each one has its own requirements about luggage size, weight, extra luggage price, need for on-line check-in and printed ticket.

Each time I fly I ask my self what are the requirements, and although I can check them online at the official website this can't be quick, sometimes I leave it for last or, with so many, I just confuse airline requirements.

Is there a website or resource that lists this information?
This would be very useful to quickly check or just compare requirements.

Comment: The requirements vary by class, country, airline and mileage.

Comment: I nominate FlyerTalk FAQs as the most reliable.

Comment: It also varies on departure city/country, and destination city/country.

Comment: http://www.edreams.com/offers/flights/airline/ may help. For baggages only there is also http://www.airline-baggage-fees.com/

Comment: @giordano why dont you write that as an answer? (couldn click in the first link though).

Comment: @nsn can't you access edreams?

Comment: @giordano now I can. The first time I tried I got an emtpy page. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- http://www.edreams.com/offers/flights/airline/ has some user reviews of airlines, but also check-in and baggage information for the major companies.
- Another site with such information is SeatGuru: http://www.seatguru.com/browseairlines/browseairlines.php
- http://www.airline-baggage-fees.com has useful information, but only for baggages.
- The most reliable resource for this information remains the official site of each airline.  Here is a list of links to the pages of baggage information for many of them: https://www.kayak.com/airline-fees